# Why seting a column in a Dataframe from a Series with different index produces a column with NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas

In the following code, I have one DataFrame with two rows and a series with two values.

I would like to set the Series values in the column of my DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 1), index=["one", "two"])
print(df)
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(2), index=["four", "five"])
df.loc[:, 0] = s
print(df)
```

However, the Series and the Dataframe doesn't have the same index. This results in NaNs in the Dataframe.

```
      0
one NaN
two NaN
```

In order to have my values in the column, I can simply use the `.values` attribute of s.

```
df.loc[:, 0] = s.values
```

**I would like to understand what is the logic behind getting NaNs when doing the former.**

Comment: how else would the two merge? It would either be index values where one way to merge is how you had attempted, or use a merge based on the common keys among the two objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before adding values to a Series/column, pandas aligns the indices.

This enables you to assign data when indices are missing or not in the same order.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 1), index=["one", "two"])
s = pd.Series([2, 1], index=["two", "one"]) # notice the different order

df.loc[:, 0] = s
print(df)

     0
one  1
two  2
```

You can check what should happen using `reindex`:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(2), index=["four", "five"])
s.reindex(df.index)

one   NaN
two   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Using `values`/`to_numpy()`, this converts the Series to numpy array and reindexing is no longer performed.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is a little counter intuitive to set NaNs because the indices are missing in the Series, instead of not changing the values at all. However, NaNs are easier to notice than a setting operation with no effect :) .

Answer (score 0):

Because indexing are not matching between df & series (s)....

on the flip; if you do s.values or s.to_list() ... it basially converts the series to array or list respectively... so no angle of indexwise mactching...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 1), index=["one", "two"])
print(df)
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(2), index=["one", "two"]) #edited here
df.loc[:, 0] = s
print(df)

            0
one -0.560306
two -0.762751
            0
one  0.281997
two  0.361495
```

Comment: Thank you. I was more interested in the reasoning behind "not setting the values if the indexes are different".